# Parsing invalid XML or HTML with XSLT in C#

Tags: c#, html, xml, templates, xslt

I recently had to write a class that would process a provided template and return the result.  I chose XSLT as my templating language due to the industry wide adoption it enjoys.  The problem I had, however, was that the provided template had several restrictions that were proving to be a pain.  Here is an example of my code:

```
public string ProcessTemplate(string template, IEnumerable<Field> fields)
{
    // Surround the supplied template with the required XML
    template = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                <xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">
                <xsl:output method=""html"" version=""2.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" indent=""yes""/>
                <xsl:template match=""/entity"">"
                    + template
                + "</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";

    // Turn our fields into XML with an "entity" tag as the root node
    var t = GetTemplateXml(fields);

    // Create a stringreader to read our template into memory
    var sr = new StringReader(t.ToString());
    var xr = new XmlTextReader(sr);

    // Now create a XmlWriter attached to a StringBuilder to contain the transformed result
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var xws = new XmlWriterSettings()
    {
        ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
    };
    var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sb, xws);

    // Create the transform object and an XmlReader for our template
    var xsl = new XslCompiledTransform();
    var xslr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(template));

    // Load our template into the transform object, transform it, and put the result into our XmlWriter (and therefore into our StringBuilder)
    xsl.Load(xslr);
    xsl.Transform(xr, xw);

    var res = sb.ToString();
    return res;
}
```

The user would provide a number of `Field` objects, which to be valid XML had to share a root node.  I called this root node "entity" but didn't want the users to have to select "entity" every time they access a field.  So I surround the template with `<xsl:template match="/entity">`, which means I can select the fields directly.  Unfortunately I still had several problems:

1. Firstly, the template I was providing had an HTML Doctype declaration at the top of the page.  I started getting errors around an "unexpected DTD declaration" because the `DOCTYPE` was appearing inside the `xsl:template` node.
2. If the user supplied any invalid XML (such as a tag that wasn't self closed and had no matching closing tag) then the parser would throw an exception, even if the HTML would have worked in a browser.  This seemed unacceptable because as much as I would like my users to supply perfectly formed XML/HTML templates, I don't want to move the burden onto the end user if it's something that I can fix.
3. In the HTML template I was testing against, the opening HTML tag was surrounded with IE conditional comments in order to supply a different class to the tag depending on the version of IE.  For instance `<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->`.  Because this is a proprietary IE syntax, XML just sees a comment and no html tag.  The closing tag at the end of the document therefore has no matching start tag and throws an exception.

As I tackled each issue one at a time the solution became less and less acceptable to me and I sought a robust solution that would not force the user to cater for the weaknesses of my template method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up settling on a solution that would allow invalid HTML and pass that responsibility back to the browser where the user expects it to lie.  Some might disagree with this approach, reasoning that it is better for the template to fail quickly and obviously so that it can be fixed.  However as I said, I am catering for an end user who has certain expectations from writing HTML - one of those is that the page will render if they provide poorly formed HTML.  Even if it renders incorrectly.

I decided that I could handle all three issues outlined above by writing a method that would prepare the template before the transform, and then a method that would clean up the result before returning it to the user.  Here they are:

```
/// <summary>
/// This function replaces all chevrons with %lt; and %gt;  Any xsl tags are left in place
/// so they can be processed, and the parent tags of xsl:attribute tags are also left
/// untouched in order that the attribute can be correctly assigned.
/// The tokens used are deliberately different from the standard tokens of &lt; and &gt; 
/// because we will want to revert these tokens later without reverting the normal tokens.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="template"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string PrepareTemplate(string template)
{
    template = Regex.Replace(template, "<", "%lt;");
    template = Regex.Replace(template, ">", "%gt;");
    template = Regex.Replace(template, "%lt;xsl:(.*?)%gt;", "<xsl:$1>");
    template = Regex.Replace(template, "%lt;/xsl:(.*?)%gt;", "</xsl:$+>");
    template = Regex.Replace(template, "%lt;(.[^%]*?)%gt;(.[^%]*?)<xsl:attribute(.*?)>", "<$1>$2<xsl:attribute$3>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    template = Regex.Replace(template, "</xsl:attribute>(.*?)%lt;/(.*?)%gt;", "</xsl:attribute>$1</$2>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    return template;
}
```

I will explain each line in turn:

1. The first line replaces opening chevrons with a %lt; token.
2. The next line replaces closing chevrons with a %gt; token.
3. This looks for any opening XSL tags and turns our tokens back into chevrons.
4. (Same as 3 but for closing XSL tags)
5. This looks for any `<xsl:attribute>` tag, and replaces the nearest preceding tokenised tag with a proper XML tag.  An xsl:attribute tag applies to the closest ancestor node, so we have to transform our tokenised tag to proper XML for it to work.
6. Similar to 5, this replaces any tokenised closing tag on the xsl:attribute parent node with the proper XML closing tag.

### Further explanation of 5 & 6

Given the following template:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="url" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="linkText" />
</a>
```

We will end up with all non XSL nodes being tokenised like so:

```
%lt;a%gt;
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="url" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="linkText" />
%lt;/a%gt;
```

Because the `a` tag is no longer a valid XML tag, the parser will not attach the attribute to the correct entity.  Worse yet it will throw an exception when it tries to attach it to the root node.  Looking for a preceding and following tag allows us to replace the `a` tag whilst leaving the rest of the document tokenised.

**Problem**

Unfortunately it has one limitation that I have noticed, which is that any non XSL tag within the `a` tag would cause the wrong tag to be replaced.  Take the following example:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="url" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="linkText" />
    <span> - Click here</span>
</a>
```

The regex would replace the closing `span` tag instead of the closing `a` tag, so we end up with this:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="url" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="linkText" />
    %lt;span%gt; - Click here</span>
%lt;/a%gt;
```

Obviously this means the opening `a` tag and the closing `span` tag don't match, which throws an exception.  The same is true if we put the span before the `xsl:attribute` tag except that the opening `span` is replaced instead of the opening `a`.  My first thought was to look for a closing tag that matched the opening tag we found, or vice versa, but as the same tag can be nested it would involve counting the number of opening and closing tags to make sure they match up.  That could get messy.

**Solution**

Thankfully this is easily solved by some normally invalid XSL.  The reason for the `xsl:attribute` is to assign an attribute to an XML node - normally putting xml inside an attribute value is invalid and would throw an exception, but because we have tokenised our XML we can do so safely.  So to add the attribute we just insert a normal `xsl:value-of` tag into the attribute like so:

```
<a href="<xsl:value-of select="logo" />">
    <xsl:value-of select="linkText" />
    <span> - Click here</span>
</a>
```

This would be invalid before we run `PrepareTemplate`, but afterwards it looks like this:

```
%lt;a href="<xsl:value-of select="logo" />"%gt;
    <xsl:value-of select="linkText" />
    %lt;span%gt; - Click here%lt;/span%gt;
%lt;/a%gt;
```

This is perfectly valid XML and has the added benefit of providing a more elegant approach (in my opinion) more akin to most templating languages.  The `xsl:attribute` will still work, but only if there are no child elements (other than xsl tags) within the tag the attribute is being applied to.

### Reverting

When we are finished processing the XML we then call the following method:

```
private string RevertTemplate(string template)
{
    template = Regex.Replace(template, "%lt;", "<");
    template = Regex.Replace(template, "%gt;", ">");
    return template;
}
```

This converts our special chevron tokens back into the proper tags while leaving normal < and > tags alone.

### Summary

To prepare our template we call `PrepareTemplate` like so:

```
template = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                    <xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0"" xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"">
                    <xsl:output method=""html"" version=""2.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" indent=""yes""/>
                    <xsl:template match=""/entity"">"
                        + PrepareTemplate(template)
                    + "</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
```

And after the XML has been transformed we revert the template like so:

```
var res = RevertTemplate(sb.ToString());
return res;
```

I hope this helps out someone facing a similar dilemma.  While not a perfect solution it is a workable one.  Obviously you should be careful if trying to use this in a high performance situation as regular expressions can slow your system right down if you are trying to process thousands of templates.  It's worth doing some checking to see if the xsl:attribute tag is even present before trying to replace its parent tags, for instance.

Good luck and feel free to offer any alternative suggestions or improvements.

Comment: You might want to have a look to the HtmlAgility pack. Regular expressions and xml, not a good idea, and performance wise Xslt is hideous all by itself.